# Fitting ARMA model with MATLAB R2012b

Tags: time-series, matlab, econometrics, fitting, arma

I want to fit an ARMA model on a time series (quarterly log returns of a 10 year bond) using MATLAB R2012b. This is part of an exercise.

I have problems with the code and the interpretation of a result.
This is the code I'm using:

```
% last element is the most recent one, first element is the oldest one
timeSeries = ...
    [0.0327; 0.0386; 0.0375; 0.0147; 0.0417; -0.0319; -0.0278; ...
    -0.0693; 0.0328; -0.0721; -0.0727; 0.0645; -0.0301; -0.0301; -0.0261; ...
    0.0313; -0.0912; -0.0235; 0.0436; -0.0714; 0.0128; 0.0506; 0.1451; ...
    0.0387; -0.0190; 0.0822; -0.0009; -0.0094; 0.0408; 0.0324; 0.0661; ...
    0.1519; 0.0713; 0.2015; 0.0353; -0.0800; 0.0079; 0.0119; -0.1376; 0.0345; ...
    0.0568; -0.3770; 0.0516; 0.0563; 0.0849; 0.0484; 0.0148; 0.0991; 0.0796; ...
    0.0872; 0.0754; -0.0473; -0.3189; 0.0478; 0.0457; 0.0183; -0.0422; ...
    -0.0528; 0.0632; -0.0287; -0.1751; 0.0238; 0.0733; -0.0177; 0.0933; ...
    0.1358; -0.0631; -0.0542; -0.0166; 0.0194; -0.0868; 0.0742; 0.0260; ...
    0.0122; 0.0634; 0.0277; 0.0171; 0.0509; 0.1551; 0.0875; 0.0535; 0.0058; ...
    0.1711; 0.1028; -0.2364; 0.0991; -0.0061; 0.0768; -0.0444; 0.2470; ...
    0.0935; -0.0983; -0.0428; -0.0852; -0.0977; 0.0094; -0.3146; 0.1685; ...
    0.0379; -0.1846; -0.3769; 0.0353; -0.1330; 0.2245; 0.0255; 0.1483; ...
    -0.0051; 0.0255; -0.0407; 0.0779; 0.0305; 0.0353; 0.0931; 0.0520; 0.1156; ...
    -0.0712; 0.0579; 0.0879];

p = 1;
q = 1;

% first way: garchfit
spec = garchset('R', p, 'M', q, 'VarianceModel', 'Constant');
[coeff, coeffErrors, llf, innovation, sigma, summary] = garchfit(spec, timeSeries);
garchdisp(coeff, coeffErrors);

% second way: arima class
[model, varCov, llf2, info2] = estimate(arima(p,0,q), timeSeries);
```

I get the following results using garchfit (coefficients equal to 1 or -1 have an absolute value very close to 1, like 0.999999998):

```
                               Standard          T     
  Parameter       Value          Error       Statistic 
 -----------   -----------   ------------   -----------
           C    0.0063979      0.022847         0.2800
       AR(1)    -1             0.025306       -39.5159
       MA(1)    1              0.040576        24.6451
           K    0.010616       0.0010517       10.0941
```

These are the results using the arima class:

```
                              Standard          t     
 Parameter       Value          Error       Statistic 
-----------   -----------   ------------   -----------
 Constant     0.00381023     0.0235065       0.162092
    AR{1}       0.638413       2.19145        0.29132
    MA{1}      -0.617482       2.26535      -0.272577
 Variance      0.0107181    0.00103327         10.373
```

**Question 1**. I believe that the two ways to fit the model should lead to the same model: an ARMA model can be represented as a GARCH model with constant variance (this is what I was taught at least, I'm no expert of GARCH models). Is it correct?

**Question 2**. Assuming that both ways should lead to the same model, why do I get very different values for coefficients AR{1} and MA{1}? Is it just related to the optimization procedure used to compute them?

**Question 3**. Assumption: the garchfit results are correct; in fact, these results are significant, while the ones computed with the arima class are not. Therefore, my univariate model becomes

$$ y_{t} = 0.0063979 - y_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t $$

where $\epsilon$ are residuals. Therefore, it is

$$ y_{t} + y_{t-1} = 0.0063979 + \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t $$

Can you help me understand what does it mean? I think it should mean that the time series is equal to its residuals, therefore the time series is a white noise according to the theory of ARMA models. Is is correct?

Thank you very much.

Comment: ARMA parameters can be estimated via Maximum likelihood. A good implementation is available at:
http://siteresources.worldbank.org/DEC/Resources/Hevia_arma_mle.m The algorithm and usage is explained at:
http://siteresources.worldbank.org/DEC/Resources/Hevia_ARMA_estimation.pdf